# MKMapView current location showing as custom pins

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, mkmapview

I have set so that my MKMapView shows the current location. I also have a custom pin implemented for other pins. However, it turns out the current location shows as a custom pin, whereas I just wanted it to be a regular blue circle (like what google map has).

I have defined the following in my code:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView: (MKMapView *) mapView viewForAnnotation: (id<MKAnnotation>) annotation MKAnnotationView *pin = (MKAnnotationView *) [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier: @"VoteSpotPin"];
    if (pin == nil)
    {
        pin = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation: annotation reuseIdentifier: @"TestPin"] autorelease];
    }
    else
    {
        pin.annotation = annotation;
    }

    [pin setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TestPin.png"]];
    pin.canShowCallout = YES;
    pin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    return pin;
}
```

How can I prevent the current location to show up as a pin?

Comment: mapView.showsUserLocation=YES then it will show current location .if you want to show pin at current location pass the current location lat lon to that annotation;

Comment: I did that and it shows the current location as a custom pin I have and not the blue circle. That is actually the real issue

Comment: have you check your application is supports location manager.issue in device or simulator

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you need to implement this:-

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView: (MKMapView *) mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>) annotation
{        
    if (annotation == mapView.userLocation)
    {
       return nil;
    }
    else
    {
       MKAnnotationView *pin = (MKAnnotationView *) [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier: @"VoteSpotPin"];
       if (pin == nil)
       {  
          pin = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation: annotation reuseIdentifier: @"TestPin"] autorelease];
       }
       else
       {
          pin.annotation = annotation;
       }           

       [pin setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TestPin.png"]];
       pin.canShowCallout = YES;
       pin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
       return pin;
    }
}
```

Comment: didn't know that mapView.userLocation is an annotation as well. Thanks! glad to know this

Answer (score 2):

For Swift:

```
if annotation is MKUserLocation {
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapViewTmp viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
    {
        if(annotation == mapView.userLocation)
            return nil;
         else
            {
MKAnnotationView *pin = (MKAnnotationView *) [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier: @"VoteSpotPin"];
            if (pin == nil)
            {

                pin = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation: annotation reuseIdentifier: @"TestPin"] autorelease];
            }
            else
            {
                pin.annotation = annotation;
            }

            [pin setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TestPin.png"]];
            pin.canShowCallout = YES;
            pin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            return pin;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Want simplest solution? Just change your object pin from `MKAnnotationView`  to `MKPinAnnotationView` it will show you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
mapView.delegate=self;



MKCoordinateRegion myRegion;

CLLocationCoordinate2D center;

center.latitude=40.4000;//spean

center.longitude=-3.6833;//firstLagi;//-5.345373;



MKCoordinateSpan span;

span.latitudeDelta=My_Span;
span.longitudeDelta=My_Span;


myRegion.center=center;
myRegion.span=span;


[mapView setRegion:myRegion animated:YES];



NSMutableArray *locations=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
Annotation *myAnn;




allList=[[AllList alloc]init];




for (int j = 0; j<[appDelegate.allListArray count]; j++)
{
    cat=@"cat";
    myAnn=[[Annotation alloc]init];

    allList=[appDelegate.allListArray objectAtIndex:j];

    location.latitude=[allList.lati doubleValue];
    location.longitude=[allList.lagi doubleValue];

    myAnn.coordinate=location;
    myAnn.title=allList.name;
    //myAnn.subtitle=allList.type;

    [locations addObject:myAnn];


}

[self.mapView addAnnotations:locations];
```